# How can i enable includes with empty string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is my code not working? I need to display div while `code = ""`.
I need to disable button in my project, if global variable code has certain parts of string.

```js
let code = "";

$(".button").click(function() {
  code = code + "z";
  console.log(code);
})

if (code.includes("z")) {
  $(".hide").css("display", "visible");
  console.log(code);

} else if (code.includes("")) {
  $(".hide").css("display", "none");
  console.log(code);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">Click me</button>
<div class="hide">Im hidden if code = "".</div>
```

Comment: its because your logic IF are out of click event and they are evaulated once on page load.

Comment: Your logic is not well designed here. You need to add the `if` and `else if` inside the click function and need to set some CSS to the `.hide` to it start with `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

in your example the if-else is executed when the script is first run. so code never includes z and the if-else check does not run on each click. try this.

```
let code = "";

$(".button").click(function() {
  code = code + "z";
  console.log(code);

  if (code.includes("z")) {
    $(".hide").css("display", "visible");
    console.log(code);

  } else if (code.includes("")) {
    $(".hide").css("display", "none");
    console.log(code);

  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since if/else is written outside of the click event, they are only executing only once, when the page loads. On clicking the button they are not executing at all. You have to execute the condition on clicking the button.

**Please Note:** [*visibility*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) is not the proper value (it is itself another property) for [*display*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property, use *block* as the property value instead.

```js
let code = "";

$(".button").click(function() {
  code = code + "z";
  console.log(code);
  
  if (code.includes("z")) {
    $(".hide").css("display", "block");
    console.log(code);
  }
  else if (code.includes("")) {
    $(".hide").css("display", "none");
    console.log(code);
  }
});

if (code.includes("")) {
  $(".hide").css("display", "none");
  console.log(code);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">Click me</button>
<div class="hide">Im hidden if code = "".</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement `if (code.includes("z")) {}` only runs once when the page loads, not everytime you click your button. Instead, you can add this check into a function and check it when the page loads and when the button is clicked by calling the function.

Also the style `display: visible` isn't valid. You need can use `display: block` instead.

See working example below:

```js
let code = "";
function checkCode() {
  if (code.includes("z")) {
    $(".hide").css("display", "block"); // you can use .show() instead of .css()
  } else if (code.includes("")) {
    $(".hide").css("display", "none"); // you can use .hide() instead of .css()
  }
}

$(".button").click(function() {
  code = code + "z";
  console.log(code);
  
  checkCode();
});

checkCode();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">Click me</button>
<div class="hide">Im hidden if code = "".</div>
```